# Using hexagonal architecture in embedded systems

Tags: embedded, software-design, hexagonal-architecture

I'm trying to work out how the hexagonal (ports and adapters) architecture might be used in the context of an embedded software system.

if I understand right, the architecture is something like this.

```
 /-----------------\        /-----------------------------\                  
 |                 |        |                             |                  
 |  Application    |        |    Domain                   |                  
 |                 |        |                             |                  
 |  +----------+   |        |  +---------+                |                  
 |  |          +-------------->|interface|                |       /-------------------\
 |  +----------+   |        |  +---------+                |       |                   |
 |                 |        |      ^                      |       |   Infrastructure  |
 |                 |        |      |                      |       |                   |
 \---------------+-/        |  +---+---+     +---------+  |       |   +----------+    |
                            |  |       +---->|interface|<-------------+          |    |
Code that allows            |  +-------+     +---------+  |       |   +----------+    |
interaction with            |                             |       |                   |
user                        \--------------------------+--/       \-----------------+-/

                                     Business logic         What we (the business)   
                                                            depend on - persistence, 
                                                            crypto services etc
```

Let's take a concrete example of where one of the user interfaces is a touch screen that the main controller talks to over a serial UART. The software sends control commands to draw elements on the screen and the user actions generate text messages.

The bits I see working in this scenario are:

1. Serial driver

   - Sends data over the UART
   - Receives data (an ISR is invoked)
2. Screen Command builder
3. Screen Response/Event parser
4. Business logic such as presenting and responding to menus, widgets etc

The bit I'm struggling with is where these pieces should reside. Intuitively, I feel it's as follows:

- **Infrastructure** - UART driver
- **Domain** - Business logic
- **Application** - Message builder/parser

But this arrangement forces a dependency between Application and Infrastructure where the parser needs to retrieve the data and the builder needs to send the data through the UART.

Bringing the messages builder and parser to Infrastructure or Domain takes the whole user interaction thing away from the Application.

Whichever way I look at it, it seems to violate some aspect of the diagram that I drew above. Any suggestions?

Comment: This seems like a bad design indeed. It should go like UART driver -> UART HAL -> protocol handler -> application logic which passes data where it needs to go. For smaller projects you might take shortcuts, but then it doesn't really make sense to discuss the program design.

Comment: @Lundin, you're probably right. in my implementation I used a new boundary called platform that contains the HAL and drivers both pointing to application and infrastructure. But I wanted to see if there's some way the traditional hex arch would work here.

Comment: I also think that 'Application' is an unfortunate name. Maybe it's short for application-frontend?

Comment: IMHO you are applying the architecture on a too low level. That a UART by itself is statically positioned somewhere is, to my understanding, not really a part of the Hexagon architecture. I could imagine a UART-holding manager as a repository in the "Infrastructure" (using your terms) which passes one of the physical UARTS (that is, a handle to a driver object for one specific physical UART) to the "Domain" which in turns gives an abstracted serial-character-based-bidirectional-communication object to the "Application".

Comment: @Vroomfondel I'n inclined to agree with you. Looking at it, most systems that use the HA I guess would use a high level API that completely ignores the underlying system whereas in the embedded world we need to provide OS interfaces, drivers and possibly common utility functions (e.g. ARRAY_SIZE(c) etc). This is what drove the need for a platform partition I guess.